# Cannot load modules/libphp5.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config

Tags: php, apache

When I run `sudo systemctl start httpd.service`, I got this.

```
apachectl[18382]: httpd: Syntax error on line 172 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp5.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
```

Evironment: Archlinux 3.10.10.1 x86_64 + php5.5.3 + apache24 from AUR.

Comment: Sounds like PHP wasn't correctly compiled. Recompile/reinstall PHP?!

Comment: Not an answer, but [this](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/apache24/) suggests it is a problem with Apache 2.4 and that module.

Comment: I remove apache24 and install apache 2.2 and it works well, it seems that module haven't been updated.